# How to detect patterns on a 1D array of measurements

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sensors

I am developing an IA algorithm for a robot that needs to follow a line. The floor will be black, with a white line and there will be different marks that determine different types of "obstacles". I'm using a sensor that gives me an array of 8 measurements of the floor, as seen on the Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmQbj.png) that give me an array of 8 measurements from 0 to 1000, where 0 there is no white and 1000 is totally white. In the examples bellow is a measurement of a white line in the middle of the sensor array and other cases.

```
int array[] = {50, 24, 9, 960, 1000, 150, 50, 45} // white line in the middle
int array2[] = {50, 24, 9, 960, 1000, 150, 50, 960} // white line in the middle and a square box on the right
int array3[] = {1000, 24, 9, 960, 1000, 150, 50, 40} // white line in the middle and a square box on the left
int array4[] = {1000, 980, 950, 0, 10, 980, 1000, 960} // black square box in the middle
```

Witch algorithms I could use to detect the patterns on the images below given this array of measurements? I do not want to use several "hardcoded" conditionals as templates, as I think it will not scale well. Im thinking on implementing a "peak counter" algorithm, but I do not know if it will work robust enough.

On the Figures we can see the different cases, the case I want to detect are the ones with the red circle.

Thanks!

[image: Sensors arrangement]
  [image: Black square]

[image: Left]
[image: Right]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about doing something simple like treating each measurement like an ***N***-dimensional vector. In your case ***N***=8. Then, all you measurements are contained in a [**hypercube**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube) with sides up to length 1000. For ***N***=8 there will be 256 corners. For each of your cases of interest, associate the hypercube corners that best match up to it. Note, some corners may not get associated. Then, for each measurement find its nearest associated hypercube corner. This tells you which case it is. You can mitigate errors by implementing some checks. For example, if the measurement is close to multiple corners (within some uncertainty threshold) then you label the measurement as being ambiguous and skip it.

It's easier to see this for the case of 3 measurements. The 8 corners of the cube could represent

```
[0,0,0] = no white
[0,0,1] = white on right
[0,1,0] = white in middle
[0,1,1] = white in middle and right
[1,0,0] = white on left
[1,0,1] = white on left and right
[1,1,0] = white on left and middle
[1,1,1] = all white
```

The case shown below is an ambiguous measurement in the middle.

[image: cube]
<sub>(source: [ctralie.com](http://www.ctralie.com/Teaching/Tetrahedron/cubevectorsdrawn.png))</sub>